# java. context.getFormattedValue() and context.webRoot() methods: what they do?

Tags: java, jsp

check the code of one of the applications, and found this line:

```
out.print(context.getFormattedValue(context.webRoot(),null));
```

I tried to find a description of methods with Google:

```
context.webRoot()
context.getFormattedValue()
```

but I could not find the official description of these methods. Why?

This is what that very specific methods?
This outdated methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"context" in your code is an object; you need to figure out the *class* of that object.  For example, HttpServlet has a "ServletContext" object which maintains the context for the servlet.  Your code probably has something that declares "context" as a specific Java type--once you know that, then you can do your web search on "ObjectClassname.webRoot()" and have some hope of figuring out what's going on.